# X728 UPS email setup

Tags: hat, ups

I`ve got an X728 ups hat and is working right, using the .sh provided by geekworm.
What I expect next is to write some code make the .sh to send an email when power is down or up, or when batteries are low (almost 3V) and is going to send the shutdown signal.
I am a newby in python, so any help will be welcome.
What I have clear:

```py
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    import email.mime.application
    import smtplib
    
    #replace the next three lines with your credentials
    from_email_addr = 'Sender_Email_ID@gmail.com'
    from_email_password = 'Password'
    to_email_addr = 'Receiver_Email_ID@gmail.com'
    
     #Create the Message
                msg = MIMEMultipart()
                msg[ 'Subject'] = 'POWER UP!!'#OR DOWN OR IS GOING TO SHUTDOWN. HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS?
                msg['From'] = from_email_addr
                msg['To'] = to_email_addr
```

from x728.sh (what appears to be x728bat.py)

```py
#X728 Battery voltage & precentage reading
#!/bin/bash

    sudo sed -e '/shutdown/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/rc.local

    echo '#!/usr/bin/env python
import struct
import smbus
import sys
import time


def readVoltage(bus):

     address = 0x36
     read = bus.read_word_data(address, 2)
     swapped = struct.unpack("<H", struct.pack(">H", read))[0]
     voltage = swapped * 1.25 /1000/16
     return voltage


def readCapacity(bus):

     address = 0x36
     read = bus.read_word_data(address, 4)
     swapped = struct.unpack("<H", struct.pack(">H", read))[0]
     capacity = swapped/256
     return capacity


bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # 0 = /dev/i2c-0 (port I2C0), 1 = /dev/i2c-1 (port I2C1)

while True:

 print "******************"
 print "Voltage:%5.2fV" % readVoltage(bus)

 print "Battery:%5i%%" % readCapacity(bus)

 if readCapacity(bus) == 100:

         print "Battery FULL"

 if readCapacity(bus) < 20:


         print "Battery LOW"
 print "******************"
 time.sleep(2)
' > /home/pi/x728bat.py
sudo chmod +x /home/pi/x728bat.py
```

So, if I write some code as

```py
#X728 Battery voltage & precentage reading
#!/bin/bash

    sudo sed -e '/shutdown/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/rc.local

    echo '#!/usr/bin/env python
import struct
import smbus
import sys
import time
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import email.mime.application
import smtplib


def readVoltage(bus):

     address = 0x36
     read = bus.read_word_data(address, 2)
     swapped = struct.unpack("<H", struct.pack(">H", read))[0]
     voltage = swapped * 1.25 /1000/16
     return voltage


def readCapacity(bus):

     address = 0x36
     read = bus.read_word_data(address, 4)
     swapped = struct.unpack("<H", struct.pack(">H", read))[0]
     capacity = swapped/256
     return capacity


bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # 0 = /dev/i2c-0 (port I2C0), 1 = /dev/i2c-1 (port I2C1)

while True:

 print "******************"
 print "Voltage:%5.2fV" % readVoltage(bus)

 print "Battery:%5i%%" % readCapacity(bus)

 if readCapacity(bus) == 100:

         print "Battery FULL"

 if readCapacity(bus) < 20:

 if readCapacity(bus) < 22
#replace the next three lines with your credentials
    from_email_addr = 'Sender_Email_ID@gmail.com'
    from_email_password = 'Password'
    to_email_addr = 'Receiver_Email_ID@gmail.com'
    
     #Create the Message
                msg = MIMEMultipart()
                msg[ 'Subject'] = 'Raspberry is going to die'
                msg['From'] = from_email_addr
                msg['To'] = to_email_addr


         print "Battery LOW"
 print "******************"
 time.sleep(2)
' > /home/pi/x728bat.py
sudo chmod +x /home/pi/x728bat.py
```

and from x728.sh too (what appears to be x728pld.py

```py
#X728 AC Power loss / power adapter failture detection
#!/bin/bash

    sudo sed -e '/button/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/rc.local

    echo '#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import email.mime.application
import smtplib

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN)

def my_callback(channel):
    if GPIO.input(6):     # if port 6 == 1
        print "---AC Power Loss OR Power Adapter Failure---"
#replace the next three lines with your credentials
    from_email_addr = 'Sender_Email_ID@gmail.com'
    from_email_password = 'Password'
    to_email_addr = 'Receiver_Email_ID@gmail.com'
    
     #Create the Message
                msg = MIMEMultipart()
                msg[ 'Subject'] = 'Power off'
                msg['From'] = from_email_addr
                msg['To'] = to_email_addr
    else:                  # if port 6 != 1
        print "---AC Power OK,Power Adapter OK---"
#replace the next three lines with your credentials
    from_email_addr = 'Sender_Email_ID@gmail.com'
    from_email_password = 'Password'
    to_email_addr = 'Receiver_Email_ID@gmail.com'
    
     #Create the Message
                msg = MIMEMultipart()
                msg[ 'Subject'] = 'Power on'
                msg['From'] = from_email_addr
                msg['To'] = to_email_addr

GPIO.add_event_detect(6, GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback)

print "1.Make sure your power adapter is connected"
print "2.Disconnect and connect the power adapter to test"
print "3.When power adapter disconnected, you will see: AC Power Loss or Power Adapter Failure"
print "4.When power adapter reconnected, you will see: AC Power OK, Power Adapter OK"

raw_input("Testing Started")
' > /home/pi/x728pld.py
sudo chmod +x /home/pi/x728pld.py
```

After some work and help from Andrew, I rewrote x728.sh Geekworm Version (from https://github.com/geekworm-com/x728/blob/master/x728.sh) as follows:

```py
#X728 RTC setting up
sudo sed -i '$ i rtc-ds1307' /etc/modules
sudo sed -i '$ i echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device' /etc/rc.local
sudo sed -i '$ i hwclock -s' /etc/rc.local
sudo sed -i '$ i #Start power management on boot' /etc/rc.local

#x728 Powering on /reboot /full shutdown through hardware
#!/bin/bash

    sudo sed -e '/shutdown/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/rc.local

    echo '#!/bin/bash

SHUTDOWN=5
REBOOTPULSEMINIMUM=200
REBOOTPULSEMAXIMUM=600
echo "$SHUTDOWN" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$SHUTDOWN/direction
BOOT=12
echo "$BOOT" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$BOOT/direction
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$BOOT/value

echo "X728 Shutting down..."

while [ 1 ]; do
  shutdownSignal=$(cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio$SHUTDOWN/value)
  if [ $shutdownSignal = 0 ]; then
    /bin/sleep 0.2
  else  
    pulseStart=$(date +%s%N | cut -b1-13)
    while [ $shutdownSignal = 1 ]; do
      /bin/sleep 0.02
      if [ $(($(date +%s%N | cut -b1-13)-$pulseStart)) -gt $REBOOTPULSEMAXIMUM ]; then
        echo "X728 Shutting down", SHUTDOWN, ", halting Rpi ..."
        sudo poweroff
        exit
      fi
      shutdownSignal=$(cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio$SHUTDOWN/value)
    done
    if [ $(($(date +%s%N | cut -b1-13)-$pulseStart)) -gt $REBOOTPULSEMINIMUM ]; then 
      echo "X728 Rebooting", SHUTDOWN, ", recycling Rpi ..."
      sudo reboot
      exit
    fi
  fi
done' > /etc/x728pwr.sh
sudo chmod +x /etc/x728pwr.sh
sudo sed -i '$ i /etc/x728pwr.sh &' /etc/rc.local 


#X728 full shutdown through Software
#!/bin/bash

    sudo sed -e '/button/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/rc.local

    echo '#!/bin/bash

BUTTON=13

echo "$BUTTON" > /sys/class/gpio/export;
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$BUTTON/direction
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$BUTTON/value

SLEEP=${1:-4}

re='^[0-9\.]+$'
if ! [[ $SLEEP =~ $re ]] ; then
   echo "error: sleep time not a number" >&2; exit 1
fi

echo "X728 Shutting down..."
/bin/sleep $SLEEP

#restore GPIO 13
echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$BUTTON/value
' > /usr/local/bin/x728softsd.sh
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/x728softsd.sh

#X728 Battery voltage & precentage reading
#!/bin/bash

    sudo sed -e '/shutdown/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/rc.local

    echo '#!/usr/bin/env python
import struct
import smbus
import sys
import time
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import email.mime.application
import smtplib
import datetime

#replace the next three lines with your credentials
    from_email_addr = 'Sender_Email_ID@gmail.com'
    from_email_password = 'Password'
    to_email_addr = 'Receiver_Email_ID@gmail.com'

#Create the Message of Shutdown
    def Send_Shutdown_email():
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg[ 'Subject'] = 'VOLTAGE IS LOW!! + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')'                    
msg['From'] = from_email_addr
msg['To'] = to_email_addr
text = MIMEText("Warning, voltage is very low! System is very close to shutdown")
msg.attach(text)
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(from_email_addr, from_email_password)
server.sendmail(from_email_addr, to_email_addr, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
print('Email sent')


def readVoltage(bus):

     address = 0x36
     read = bus.read_word_data(address, 2)
     swapped = struct.unpack("<H", struct.pack(">H", read))[0]
     voltage = swapped * 1.25 /1000/16
     return voltage


def readCapacity(bus):

     address = 0x36
     read = bus.read_word_data(address, 4)
     swapped = struct.unpack("<H", struct.pack(">H", read))[0]
     capacity = swapped/256
     return capacity


bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # 0 = /dev/i2c-0 (port I2C0), 1 = /dev/i2c-1 (port I2C1)

while True:

 print "******************"
 print "Voltage:%5.2fV" % readVoltage(bus)

 print "Battery:%5i%%" % readCapacity(bus)

 if readCapacity(bus) == 100:

         print "Battery FULL"

if readCapacity(bus) < 22:
    
    Send_Shutdown_email()

 if readCapacity(bus) < 20:

         print "Battery LOW"
 print "******************"
 time.sleep(2)
' > /home/pi/x728bat.py
sudo chmod +x /home/pi/x728bat.py

#X728 AC Power loss / power adapter failture detection
#!/bin/bash

    sudo sed -e '/button/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/rc.local

    echo '#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import email.mime.application
import smtplib
import datetime

#replace the next three lines with your credentials
    from_email_addr = 'Sender_Email_ID@gmail.com'
    from_email_password = 'Password'
    to_email_addr = 'Receiver_Email_ID@gmail.com'


#Create the Message of Power Down
    def Send_PowerDown_email():
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg[ 'Subject'] = 'POWER DOWN!! + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')'                    
    msg['From'] = from_email_addr
    msg['To'] = to_email_addr
    text = MIMEText("Power Down! Energy has left the room! Did you pay the bill??")
    msg.attach(text)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(from_email_addr, from_email_password)
    server.sendmail(from_email_addr, to_email_addr, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
    print('---AC Power Loss OR Power Adapter Failure---Email sent')

#Create the Message of Power Up
    def Send_PowerUP_email():
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg[ 'Subject'] = 'POWER UP!! + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')'                      
    msg['From'] = from_email_addr
    msg['To'] = to_email_addr
    text = MIMEText("Power Up! The energy has come to us! :-)")
    msg.attach(text)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(from_email_addr, from_email_password)
    server.sendmail(from_email_addr, to_email_addr, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
    print('---AC Power OK,Power Adapter OK---Email sent')


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN)

def my_callback(channel):
    if GPIO.input(6):     # if port 6 == 1
        Send_PowerDown_email()
    else:                  # if port 6 != 1
        Send_PowerUP_email()

GPIO.add_event_detect(6, GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback)

print "1.Make sure your power adapter is connected"
print "2.Disconnect and connect the power adapter to test"
print "3.When power adapter disconnected, you will see: AC Power Loss or Power Adapter Failure"
print "4.When power adapter disconnected, you will see: AC Power OK, Power Adapter OK"

raw_input("Testing Started")
' > /home/pi/x728pld.py
sudo chmod +x /home/pi/x728pld.py
```

I expect it will work!

Comment: Have you had a look at the x728bat.py program to see how that reads the voltage and x728pld.py to see about the status?  Program names taken from https://raspberrypiwiki.com/X728-Software

Comment: I edited after some changes in x728bat.py and x728pld.py, but it is not working yet....

Comment: I would not expect that to send a message - you are only creating the message details in the two samples you have posted. You need to be logging in to the server and sending the mail https://realpython.com/python-send-email/ or https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/using-python-to-send-email/ have examples that are a lot simpler than mime handling.

Comment: I will try... And tell how it went!  Thanks!

Comment: And I have to define 3 or more different Sendmails, power up, power down, battery low, etc. And add to the if conditions. Is it right??

Comment: I would set the destination etc once and only set the message in the IF blocks.  Then when all IF blocks are checked you send the message.  By adding lines to the message you can cope with multiple conditions (e.g. no power and low battery).  Obviously, any send needs your WiFi, router, modem etc to be up and running.

Comment: Of course @Andrew that is mandatory to be connected to the net to send mails...

Comment: I have rewrited the x728.sh  Please have a look. I think it is more accurate to send notifications. Are defined 3 different cases, Power up, Power Down and low voltage.

Comment: I would make a copy of the code / SD card and test it TBH.  That does mean pulling the plug hence the backup just in case the card corrupts.  Keep the risk to a minimum by not running anything else at the time.

Comment: That's exactly what I plan to do. To test it in a raspi with the x728 hat with nothing else than raspbian at the sd. I will inform of results!

Comment: Is it working fine? I would like to use it in my project. Please contact me.

Comment: Hi @YvetteLee, I didn't test it. I was writing code but a new project started and I've been working on it. You can try it and tell how it's going. I will help you with dev